# Jitbit macro recorder cannot figure out why this is not working

Tags: automation

[image] I am trying to make something check for a color in 4 different places and press an arrow key if it is but it is just not working and I cant find out why.

I also tried using the else statements but it still was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are multiple errors in the syntax, all the commands in the 1st and 2nd if statements are not linked, (i think that the program is a bit confusing and putting commands inside an if statement it's messy). Secondly if after you fixed that you still see that it doesn't work i would recommend replacing the GOTO function with a LOOP function, (in my experience works better). hope i helped despite the long time!